# Creating a new folder with resharper generate option

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

With Resharper generate option (Alt+Insert), you can create a new folder from the solution explorer in Visual Studio.

I always used this feature for some years.

I click on an existing folder or at the root of a project and press 'Alt+Insert' and the last option is 'New Folder'.

[image]

Today, one of my co-worker who have seen this feature on my computer just tried to reproduce the behavior on his computer but without success; the 'New folder' option is not visible.

Is there any option in Resharper to be able to see this option in the generate popup?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely keyboard shortcut got messed up. Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.

Search for Resharper_Generate command and assign your preferred shortcut key (alt + insert). That should do the trick.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "New Folder" option only appears when the focus is on a folder or a project. If you display the menu on a file, it doesn't appear.

Comment: This is exactly what I said in my question ... "I click on an existing folder or at the root of a project and press 'Alt+Insert' and the last option is 'New Folder'"

Comment: Let me rephrase - this is the only reason I know off that prevents the "New Folder" item from appearing in the list. If the list is being displayed and has items on it, then the only suggestion I can give is that the solution explorer doesn't have a folder or project selected. While I can see that you've got a folder or project selected, are you sure you're colleague is also doing this?